# how to get one object of array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I use tagify plugin. In my Laravel application controller I try to get tags:

code:

```
$tags = $request->tags;
```

result: (returned as string)

```
[ { value: "css" }, { value: "dfs" } ]
```

I tried `$tags = json_decode($tags);` to convert to array. This returns below result:

```
[
  {
    value: "css"
  },
  {
    value: "dfs"
  }
]
```

I just need **css** and **dfs** (no need value: and double quotes). How to get these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do using Laravel's collections

```php
$json = '[ { "value": "css" }, { "value": "dfs" } ]';
$json = json_decode($json);
return collect($json)->pluck('value')->toArray();
```

Results:

```
[
  "css",
  "dfs"
]
```